# sendto() with an uninitalized char * buffer

Tags: c, sockets

I had an error with the following code, wherein it would return to me that sendto failed because "Address family not supported by protocol".  I realized my mistake on the 3rd line, leaving a semicolon after the for loop declaration.  Once I removed this, everything worked fine.

```
struct sockaddr_in their_addr;

if ((numbytes=recvfrom(sockfd, buf, 512, 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1 ) {
    perror("recvfrom") ;
    exit(1) ;
}

char thedata[512];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 512; i++);
{
thedata[i] = 'a';
}
unsigned int addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
if ((numbytes=sendto(sockfd, thedata, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, 
       addr_len)) == -1 ) {
                    perror("sendto") ;
                    exit(1) ;
    }
```

My question is why that message specifically was returned to me.  I sent an array with uninitialized values, but my assumption was that because the char array was initialized to have 512 elements, that it would have memory allocated for all 512 elements in a row.  Why doesn't it send the garbage values?  It's a question of curiosity more than anything, but I'd love to know more about this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Show us more about `their_addr`. Where you allocate it, how you initialize it etc.

Comment: Added it.  It seems as though abligh was right, the for loop was causing me to access the wrong memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your loop exits, `i` is 512, so `thedata[i]` points to beyond the end of `thedata[]`. I am guessing this overwrote `their_addr`, specifically the protocol which from memory is at the head of the `struct`.

Please insert the normal warning here about the fact you overwrote memory so behaviour is undefined and anything could have happened.

Comment: It was pretty simple then.  So despite the semicolon error, the code inside the brackets will still execute?  I did not know that.  Upon setting the length of the loop variable to 511, the code executes as expected despite the error.

Comment: Yes. If your block in `{}` is not guarded by a `for`, `while`, `if` or whatever, it will just run once.

Comment: ... well, exactly the same number of times as what's immediately outside the block.